# Google InApp Review keeps redirecting to the Store

Tags: android

Ok so i was given the task to update our current flow which is redirecting the user to the Store , to an in app review flow.

So when i started digging in the code i figured out that it SHOULD BE ALREADY in an app review flow...

based on what google says here :

*To integrate in-app reviews in your app, your app must use version 1.8.0 or higher of the Play Core library.*
from : https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-review

```
   private fun goToGooglePlayReview() {
        val manager = ReviewManagerFactory.create(this)
        val request = manager.requestReviewFlow()
        request.addOnCompleteListener { request ->
            if (request.isSuccessful) {
                // We got the ReviewInfo object
                val reviewInfo = request.result
                val flow = manager.launchReviewFlow(this, reviewInfo)
            } else {
                // There was some problem, continue regardless of the result.
            }
        }
    }
```

this is hte code im currently using which is the same as you can find here :

https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-review/kotlin-java

and the version im using is :
com.google.android.play:core:1.10.3@aar

so what am i doing wrong exactly cuz i cannot pinpoint, it should be already doing the in app flow and not redirecting the user to the play store.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently all i had to do was update playServicesAuthVersion from 20.3.0 to 20.5.0